# Complexity of n-rooks completion

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, np-hardness

I am motivated by the post, [Complexity of n-queens-completion](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/38972/495). I am interested in completion problem of non-attacking rooks on a chessboard.

Input: Given a chessboard of size $n*n$ with $n-k$ rooks placed in non-attacking positions, and certain chessboard diagonals represented by multi-set of integers $D=\{j_1, j_2, ..., j_k\}$

Output: Can we place additional $k$ rooks such all $n$ rooks are non-attacking and each new rook is placed on exactly one diagonal in $D$?

Has anyone investigated the complexity of this problem? Is it NP-complete?